# Jira xRay test management dataset import

Tags: testing, jira, jira-xray

Does anyone know if it is possible to bulk import many datasets for many tests at once in xRay test management of the Jira cloud?

for e.g. with:

1. REST API
2. GraphQL
3. xRay importer
4. ...

Comment: If the provided answer helped, can I kindly ask you to mark as correct? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately and currently this isn't yet possible. I would suggest that you [reach out](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/user/login?destination=portal%2F2) Xray team and ask for an improvement request.
I noticed that [this suggestion is already on the backlog](https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAYCLOUD-3972), so you can even vote and watch that improvement.
You can see the list of available operations in Xray documentation, on the related REST and GraphQL endpoints documents:

- https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Version+2
- https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/doc/graphql/